# Perl and Template Toolkit: object stringify in custom filter

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

in my template(via `Template Toolkit`), I pass a DateTime object(from `DBIx::Class` and  `DBIx::Class::InflateColumn::DateTime`). I can do obj.year and all other DateTime operations in my template. But the object gets stringified in my custom filter. I am basically calling `[% user.last_visited_date | time_ago %]` where time_ago is a custom filter basically looks like this:

```
sub timeago { 
   sub { my $datetime_obj = shift; #do more work }
}
```

here I am expecting a DateTime obj in the custom filter but instead it is stringify..

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a filter for that, write a [custom plugin](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template/Plugin.html) instead:

```
[% YourPlugin.time_ago(user.last_visited_date) %]
```

Or add a [custom vmethod](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html#section_Defining_Custom_Virtual_Methods):

```
[% user.last_visited_date.time_ago %]
```

Filters are meant for text mangling such as HTML encoding and the like.

Comment: thanks. I have opted for vmethod and using the following works.`my $tt = Template->new;
$tt->context->define_vmethod( 'hash', 'timeago', \&time_ago );`